# I think I'm using React modules in a wrong way - state management in particular. How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs

I have a module Schedule that consists of dateRangeSetter (that sets the date range) and passes that information to the timeline, that displays some data from that date range. All three modules have `fromDate` and `untilDate` state variables. Additionally I pass the `handleChange` callback method to my dateRangeSetter, that takes the setter's from and until and passes to schedule to set that there. And this is where I think I have a problem. Each time I update `from` and/or `until` date in dateRangeSetter I need to call the callback function to update that state in my schedule. It doesn't feel right. Shouldn't that happen automatically - everytime the state of setter changes, the state of Schedule is updated? And if so - how to do it? I have written a bit of a code in React so far and suddently I feel like I am missing some very important, basic information.

Here is my Schedule:

```
export default function Schedule() {
    let today = new Date();
    const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [untilDate, setUntilDate] = useState(quarterLater(today));
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const data = useData({isProject, fromDate, untilDate, setError});
    if (!data) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>
    }

    const handleDateChange = ({from, until}) => {
        setFromDate(from);
        setUntilDate(until);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <DateRangeSetter
                handleDateChange={handleDateChange}
            />
            <Switch
                key={"isProject"}
                isOn={isProject}
                handleToggle={() => changeView(!isProject)}
                labelA={"by Person"}
                labelB={"by Project"}
            />
            {data && <Timeline data={data} fromDate={fromDate} untilDate={untilDate}}
        </>
    )
}
```

and here is my DateRangeSetter:

```
export default function DateRangeSetter({handleDateChange}) {
    const today = new Date();
    const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(today);
    const [untilDate, setUntilDate] = useState(quarterLater(today));
    // Represents the selected date range view: true for quarterly, false for yearly.
    const [isQuarterlyView, setQuarterlyView] = useState(true);


    const handleFromDateChange = (from) => {
        setFromDate(from);
        const until = isQuarterlyView ? quarterLater(from) : yearLater(from);
        setUntilDate(until);
        handleDateChange({from, until});
    }

    const changeToPreviousDateRange = () => {
        const currentFrom = fromDate;
        const newFrom = isQuarterlyView ? quarterEarlier(currentFrom) : yearEarlier(currentFrom);
        setFromDate(newFrom);
        setUntilDate(currentFrom);
        handleDateChange({newFrom, currentFrom});
    }

    const changeToNextDateRange = () => {
        const currentUntil = untilDate;
        const newUntil = isQuarterlyView ? quarterLater(currentUntil) : yearLater(currentUntil);
        setFromDate(currentUntil);
        setUntilDate(newUntil);
        handleDateChange({currentUntil, newUntil})

    }

    const handleChangeOfRange = () => {
        const newRange = !isQuarterlyView;
        const newUntil = newRange ? quarterLater(fromDate) : yearLater(fromDate);
        setUntilDate(newUntil);
        handleDateChange({fromDate, newUntil});
        setQuarterlyView(newRange);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className={DateRangeSetterStyles.container}>
                <Toggle
                    id="isQuarterlyView"
                    className={DateRangeSetterStyles.toggle}
                    defaultChecked={true}
                    onChange={handleChangeOfRange}
                    icons={{
                        unchecked: <Image src={year_icon} alt={"12"} width={18} height={18}/>,
                        checked: <Image src={quarter_icon} alt={"3"} width={18} height={18}/>
                    }}
                />
                <label htmlFor='isQuarterlyView'>View one {isQuarterlyView ? "quarter" : "year"}</label>
            </div>
            <div className={DateRangeSetterStyles.container}>
                <Button className={DateRangeSetterStyles.buttonPrimary}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={changeToPreviousDateRange}
                        title={"Date-back"}
                >
                    <span className={DateRangeSetterStyles.buttonLabel}> &#x3c;&#x3c; </span>
                </Button>
                <p className={DateRangeSetterStyles.currentRangeDisplay}>
                    From
                </p>
                <DatePicker
                    selected={fromDate}
                    onChange={(new_date) => handleFromDateChange(new_date)}
                    dateFormat="d MMMM, yyyy"
                    className={DateRangeSetterStyles.customDatePicker}
                    todayButton="Today"
                />
                <p className={DateRangeSetterStyles.currentRangeDisplay}>
                    until <strong>{convertDateToString(untilDate)}</strong>
                </p>
                <Button className={DateRangeSetterStyles.buttonPrimary}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={changeToNextDateRange}
                        title={"Date-forward"}
                >
                    <span className={DateRangeSetterStyles.buttonLabel}> &#x3e;&#x3e; </span>
                </Button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Passing a state setter to a child component isn't uncommon at all.  But you do appear to be *duplicating* state.  If `Schedule` has a `fromDate` and an `untilDate`, why does `DateRangeSetter` need to have those too?  Why does this component hierarchy need two distinct versions of each of those values?

Comment: This does make sense. I might indeed not need this duplicated. Although is that correct to create a module which only task is to change its parents state?

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't that happen automatically - everytime the state of setter changes, the state of Schedule is updated?

There's no reason for that to happen automatically.  If Component B internally updates its own state, why should Component A respond to that in any way if you don't tell it to?

It sounds like you're expecting state across the application to update itself *if it shares the same name*.  In both components you have these:

```
const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(new Date());
const [untilDate, setUntilDate] = useState(quarterLater(today));
```

If you're expecting the state values in both components to always be the same, should you really be declaring new state values then?  Or should the parent component own the state values and just provide them to the child component?

As a fairly close analogy... Imagine a function (instead of a component) which calls another function.  If both functions declare local variables of the same name, those variables have nothing to do with each other.  But if the parent function *passes* those values to the child function, the child function can use the same values that the parent function has.

If this is the behavior you're looking for then you can achieve it the same way you pass the function to the child component... by passing state values as well:

```
<DateRangeSetter
  fromDate={fromDate}
  untilDate={untilDate}
  handleDateChange={handleDateChange}
/>
```

And in the child component:

```
export default function DateRangeSetter({handleDateChange, fromDate, untilDate}) {
```

Then remove the local state values from the child component.  At that point `Schedule` would own these state values and `DateRangeSetter` would expect these values as props.

Comment: That all makes sense, thank you so much! Is that though the correct architecture where we create a module which only task is to change the parents state?

Comment: @Malvinka: What's "correct" is often a matter of opinion and depends heavily on the overall needs of the system being built.  But it's certainly not *uncommon* for a component to receive values and callback functions as props.